# can't reindex Product Prices

Tags: magento-1.7, product, price, reindex

```
2013-12-18T12:48:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '373-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY' Trace: #0 /html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(564): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(122): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_movePriceDataToIndexTable()
#7 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->reindexAll()
#8 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#13 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#14 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /html/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /html/magento/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: I have seen this error, did this happen after you uploaded new or updated products?

Comment: yes this is after new product import

Comment: Here is my post with how I solved it http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/cant-re-index-after-product-import

Comment: I experienced the same problem but couldn't reproduce it reliably.